# When does a FileSystemWatcher.Created event fire within a directory?

Tags: c#, file, windows-services, filesystemwatcher

I am currently designing a Windows Service that will watch a folder for a file which is copied from another folder automatically. Will an event fire as soon as it sees this copy happening or after when the copy has completed?

Or is best to poll the folder every minute lets say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will an event fire as soon as it sees this copy happening

Yes.

> Or is best to poll the folder every minute lets say?

That too, as a FileSystemWatcher can miss certain events, especially under stress (for example when a lot of files are being created in rapid succession).

Comment: Thank you for the informed response, is there a mechanism which I could use to process this file after the copy is complete?

Comment: That depends on what "process" means.

Comment: Get the file size, so I can the move the file into another directory

Comment: @JohnCooling The usual technique is to continually try to open the file and handle the error. since the copying process locks it until complete. There's quite a few questions and answers on SO for it.